# after_initialize never invoked in Rails 3 via mixin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, mixins

I am using a mixin to add some functionality to my model (Person). In the mixin I need some initializations to be done so I am trying to use the "after_initialize" callback macro to invoke an initialization method. The model (Person) is only a base class for some other models.

The problem I am having is that it gets never called. I tried to debug it but the breakpoint never got hit. Also logging gives me no output.

I couldn`t find any help (as this construct should be working in Rails 3 according to the Api docs and some posts here).

*/lib/mymodule.rb*

```
module MyModule
    after_initialize :generate_ids

    def generate_ids
      logger.info "invoked" #never hit
    end
end
```

*/models/person.rb*

```
require "mymodule"

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    include MyModule
end
```

*/models/customer.rb*

```
class Customer < Person
  # nothing so far
end
```

*/controllers/customers_controller.rb (action => new)*

```
# GET /customers/new
# GET /customers/new.json
def new
  @person = Customer.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @customer }
  end
end
```

Please be indulgent to me as I am a "newbie" to RoR.

Thank you very much !

Best regards,
Thomas

**UPDATE**

After restarting the local app server it gives me the following exception:

> ActionController::RoutingError (undefined method `after_initialize' for SequentialRecord:Module):

I assume this callback can`t be used in mixins ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like that (not tested).

```
module MyModule
  def self.included(base)
    base.after_initialize :generate_ids
  end

  def generate_ids
    logger.info "invoked" #never hit
  end
end
```